# Data structure design for limited memory map with entry timeout

Tags: data-structures

This is an interview question I came across for a big software major.

Design a data structure for a server which can store atmost 100 records, 2 functions are used to access server get(k) ,put(k,v,x).
Where k is key and v is corresponding value and x is the expiry time before which this record can't be removed.

Approach I have come so far: Maintain two datastructures.

Hashmap: stores key, value pair.
PriorityQueue: Create a priorityqueue in order of expiry times of record.
And each entry in queue, will also have key value, so that when a record expires, we can remove the key, value pair from hashmap in O(1) time.

I would like to ask, can we design a better solution for this question.

Comment: What have you tried so far? If this is homework, we're happy to help you provided that you demonstrate you've made a good honest effort and scope the question more narrowly.

Comment: Any comments on the edit??